# Search in a string during CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to join two tables for some data validation.  One table has phone numbers. the second file has all the notes/records from an account, where the phone number could appear in different fields.  I am using a CASE WHEN to join the tables on customer ID, but that gives me the phone number from table 1 and then all the fields from table 2 as I can't look for hte phone number.
Table 1

```
`    Account    phone
ABCD    555666
ABCD    555667
ABCD    555668
DEFGJ   98765
DEFGH   98754
JFH 65482
JHA 65462
`
```

TAble 2

```
`    Account    record  rec1    rec2    rec3    rec4    rec5
ABCD    PH  HP 55566    WP 555667   OP 555668       
DEFGJ   PH      HP987654            
DEFGH   PH          OP98754     
JFH PH  HP65482 MP56565             
JHA PH  HP 65462                
`
```

I have tried using like, trim.

```
`
    select a.account, a.phone,
CASE
WHEN a.phone LIKE concat('%',b.rec1,'%') THEN b.rec1
WHEN a.phone LIKE concat('%',b.rec2,'%') THEN b.rec2
WHEN a.phone LIKE concat('%',b.rec3,'%') THEN b.rec3
WHEN a.phone LIKE concat('%',b.rec4,'%') THEN b.rec4
WHEN a.phone LIKE concat('%',b.rec5,'%') THEN b.rec5
ELSE NULL
END AS found_phone
from table1 a
left join table2 b
on a.account = b.account
`
```

I would hope to see this as my results

```
`
    Account phone   found phone
ABCD    555666  HP 555666
ABCD    555667  WP 555667
ABCD    555668  OP 555668
DEFGJ   98765   HP98765
DEFGH   98754   OP98754
JFH 65482   HP65482 MP56565
JHA 65462   HP 65462
`
```

Comment: Where do `a` and `b` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your approach is correct but you interchanged the column to match

```
   WHEN b.rec1 LIKE concat('%',a.phone,'%') THEN b.rec1
   ......
```

another approach is to use `instr()` function

```
select a.account, a.phone
    , case when instr(b.rec1, a.phone) > 0 then b.rec1
        when instr(b.rec2, a.phone) > 0 then b.rec2
        when instr(b.rec3, a.phone) > 0 then b.rec3
        when instr(b.rec4, a.phone) > 0 then b.rec4
        when instr(b.rec5, a.phone) > 0 then b.rec5
     else '' end as found_phone
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.account = b.account
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be joining the account table to a subquery of unions which converts the numbers from wide to tall format:

```
SELECT
    t1.Account,
    t1.phone,
    t2.rec AS "found phone"
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Account, rec1 AS rec FROM Table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT Account, rec2 FROM Table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT Account, rec3 FROM Table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT Account, rec4 FROM Table2 UNION ALL
    SELECT Account, rec5 FROM Table2
) t2
    ON t1.Account = t2.Account
WHERE
    t2.rec IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    t1.Account,
    t1.phone;
```